# iOS: Adding sub view from AppDelegate not loading

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, subview

I'm trying to add a subview from the AppDelegate because to the main viewController because I want to show that subview in all the child view controllers.

I have add it a navigation controller to my story board.

Here is my code:

```
var navBar = UINavigationController()


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.addViewToController()
    return true
}

func addViewToController()  {
    self.navBar = (window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)!
    let frame = CGRectMake(0, navBar.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20, navBar.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 30)
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.frame = frame
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
     window?.addSubview(newView)   
}
```

The code is been executed but the subview is never been add it. Any of you knows why or what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to change one line and the following update worked for me.

Retype your last line of code in `application didFinishLaunching` method

```
 window?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(newView)
```